Indian citizen applying for Singapore tourist visa while residing in the US (choice of authorized agent)

I'm residing in California. The nearest Singapore consulute would be in San Francisco. It would seem that they're not accepting applications
I don't have a local contact (My understanding is that this would have made the process a lot easier)
Looking at the guidelines in the government website here, it would seem that I'll have to use an authorised visa agent

Is VFS global now my only option here? I was hoping that an alternative existed as my previous experiences with them have been really bad.

The embassy in DC seems to accept visa applications in person and by mail, if this page is up to date. There is an e-mail address on the same page you could use to enquire, and a phone number here

It seems VFS global is the only authorized agent that one can use for someone with bay area residency and Indian citizenship.
Unfortunately, there site didn't have any appointment slots whatsoever. They don't even show options far in the future. Customer care was unresponsive (by mail or phone). A ticket was 'created' but there was no follow-up whatosever (they were supposed to do so in 48 working hours). They answered the phone after some waiting but it again no follow up by email.
The reviews for using the walkin option in the VAC center are quite bad and the site is broken when you try to but the premium option to do so.
I'd advice anyone in a similar situation to mine to use the transit stay option (4 days) or try to go through a local contact

Thanks for returning to report your experience.  For future readers, please note that the transit stay option (VFTV) is only applicable if you're stopping in Singapore on your way somewhere else; it's not available if Singapore is your only destination.

Hi I am in a similar situation (travelling as a tourist to Singapore) with no available visa-slots and I am an Indian passport holder residing in Bay area and with no local contacts in Singapore. Could you get the visa and how did you finally manage it ? This information will be helpful for my process.

Singapore - Malaysia trip will cover that though.
